# Create BigQuery table from existing table, including _PARTITIONTIME

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I want to create a new table from an existing one, and add one column. But, and this seems to make this tricky, I want it to be partitioned by _PARTITIONTIME.

I know I can create a table from an existing table, like so:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE `mydataset.mytable_new`
AS SELECT * FROM `mydataset.mytable` 
--JOIN the new column here
LIMIT 0
```

I also know that I can create a partitioned table, like so:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE `mydataset.mytable_new`
(
  date DATE,
  var1 STRING,
  var2 INT64,
  --add new column here
)
PARTITION BY DATE(_PARTITIONTIME);
```

But: How can I combine the two? I tried this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE `mydataset.mytable_new`
PARTITION BY DATE(_PARTITIONTIME)
AS SELECT * FROM `mydataset.mytable`
-- JOIN new column here
LIMIT 0
```

However, this gives me the error '*Unrecognized name: _PARTITIONTIME*'.

Any hints are greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a documented limitation of the partitioning expression of the CREATE TABLE syntax:

https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/data-definition-language#partition_expression

> _PARTITIONDATE. Partition by ingestion time with daily partitions. This syntax cannot be used with the AS query_statement clause.

I believe you should be able to split the work.  Use a statement to create the new table, then issue INSERT statement(s) to populate from the original table.

However, if you're already dealing with a sizable table, you may want to re-consider this partitioning scheme.  By default, all the data from the original table would land in a single partition (the current date).

Comment: Thanks for pointing at the right part of the documentation, it's helpful to learn that it's a documented limitation!

Comment: Regarding the partition the data would go into, you could do this, no?


```INSERT INTO `mytable_new` (
  _PARTITIONTIME,
  var1,
  var2
)

(SELECT
  _PARTITIONTIME,
  mo.var1,
  at.var2,
FROM
  `mytable_old mo`
  LEFT JOIN `another_table` at ...)```

If you do it like this it would go into the original date partitions, wouldn't it?

Comment: Please ask new questions in a new thread. It will increase question visibility and chances of getting an answer.

Answer (score 0):

You may try like :

```
CREATE TABLE
  mydataset.newtable (transaction_id INT64, transaction_date DATE)
PARTITION BY
  transaction_date
AS SELECT transaction_id, transaction_date FROM mydataset.mytable
```

From doc : [cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/creating-partitioned-tables#sql](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/creating-partitioned-tables#sql)

Comment: That doesn't work. It's basically the same as my last query above, but partitioning by a "normal" column. This doesn't seem to work for the _PARTITIONTIME pseudo column.

Answer (score 0):

I've had a similar problem and found it is possible to use three statements to get the desired approach. In my case, I wanted to **both** omit columns from a seed table, but also add a new column. Given that I had a large number of columns and I had to repeat this process for 10+ tables, I didn't want to go through the effort of discovering the types for every column. Here were my requirements:

- Use the existing schema, omitting columns I don't want
- Modify the type of an existing column (`Date`)
- Add a new column (`metadata`)
- Final table will be partitioned by `_PARTITIONDATE`
- Can copy selected data into the final table

The result, left fully in tact for clarity:

```sql
-- Create base table
CREATE TEMP TABLE p_ad_group_performance
AS
  SELECT
    TIMESTAMP(Date) as Date,
    PartnerName,
    Advertiser,
    Campaign,
    AdGroup,
    DeviceType,
    AdvertiserCurrencyCode,
    CreativeDurationInSeconds,
    Creative,
    PartnerCurrencyCode,
    Impressions,
    Clicks,
    Player25Complete,
    Player50Complete,
    Player75Complete,
    PlayerCompletedViews,
    TotalSecondsInView,
    CompanionClicks,
    CompanionImpressions,
    PartnerCostPartnerCurrency,
    SampledViewedImpressions,
    SampledTrackedImpressions,
    PlayerStarts,
    _01ClickConversion,
    _01ClickConversionRevenue,
    _01TotalClickViewConversions,
    _01ViewThroughConversion,
    _01ViewThroughConversionRevenue,
    _01TotalClickViewConversionRevenue,
    STRUCT('migrated' as filename, 'migrated' as location, _PARTITIONTIME as uploaded_at, _PARTITIONTIME as last_modified ) as metadata
  FROM trade_desk.p_ad_group_performance WHERE DATE(_PARTITIONTIME) = "2022-12-06" LIMIT 1;

-- Create partitioned version of base table
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS trade_desk.p_ad_group_performance
LIKE p_ad_group_performance
PARTITION BY _PARTITIONDATE;

-- Populate the final table with the seed data
INSERT trade_desk.p_ad_group_performance (
  Date,
  PartnerName,
  Advertiser,
  Campaign,
  AdGroup,
  DeviceType,
  AdvertiserCurrencyCode,
  CreativeDurationInSeconds,
  Creative,
  PartnerCurrencyCode,
  Impressions,
  Clicks,
  Player25Complete,
  Player50Complete,
  Player75Complete,
  PlayerCompletedViews,
  TotalSecondsInView,
  CompanionClicks,
  CompanionImpressions,
  PartnerCostPartnerCurrency,
  SampledViewedImpressions,
  SampledTrackedImpressions,
  PlayerStarts,
  _01ClickConversion,
  _01ClickConversionRevenue,
  _01TotalClickViewConversions,
  _01ViewThroughConversion,
  _01ViewThroughConversionRevenue,
  _01TotalClickViewConversionRevenue,
  metadata
)
SELECT
  TIMESTAMP(Date) as Date,
  PartnerName,
  Advertiser,
  Campaign,
  AdGroup,
  DeviceType,
  AdvertiserCurrencyCode,
  CreativeDurationInSeconds,
  Creative,
  PartnerCurrencyCode,
  Impressions,
  Clicks,
  Player25Complete,
  Player50Complete,
  Player75Complete,
  PlayerCompletedViews,
  TotalSecondsInView,
  CompanionClicks,
  CompanionImpressions,
  PartnerCostPartnerCurrency,
  SampledViewedImpressions,
  SampledTrackedImpressions,
  PlayerStarts,
  _01ClickConversion,
  _01ClickConversionRevenue,
  _01TotalClickViewConversions,
  _01ViewThroughConversion,
  _01ViewThroughConversionRevenue,
  _01TotalClickViewConversionRevenue,
  STRUCT('migrated' as filename, 'migrated' as location, _PARTITIONTIME as uploaded_at, _PARTITIONTIME as last_modified ) as metadata
FROM trade_desk.p_ad_group_performance WHERE DATE(_PARTITIONTIME) = "2022-12-06";
```

Honestly, it's more lines of code than I would really like, but it seems to be the only way to get around the restrictions of using `_PARTITIONDATE` as the partition. Most of it is simply copying and pasting the same column references. The original tables for me were 60+ columns, if you were only skipping one or two you could simply use the `EXCEPT` keyword.

Hope this helps!